# Magento2 product collection returning empty value instead of 0 (zeros)

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I built my own product collection which I use for my own shop dashboard. What it should do is for each selected product to go through the last 13 months and show me the amount that was sold.

```
...    
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory, // for bestseller
    ...
    array $data = []
)
{
$this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
...
parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

and here is the function

```
public function getMonthCollection($from, $to) 
{
    $bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
    $bestSellerProdcutCollection->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setPeriod('month');    
    $datefrom = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$from.' month'));
    $dateto = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$to.' month'));
    $bestSellerProdcutCollection->addFieldToFilter('period',array('gt'=>$datefrom));
    $bestSellerProdcutCollection->getSelect()->group('Product_Name')->order('Product_Name ASC'); 
    return $bestSellerProdcutCollection;
}
```

This returns a list of all the products from each month and everything is fine.

I get a list like this:

| Product | month | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12/2023 | 150 |
| A | 01/2024 | 200 |
| A | 02/2024 | 250 |
| B | 12/2023 | 500 |
| B | 01/2024 | 600 |
| B | 02/2024 | 500 |

This fine as I can put all these values in arrays and create my own individueal-style table and dashboard look.

The problem:
Let's say product A was out of stock in January and I made 0 sales with it. I want the report to be like this:

| Product | month | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12/2023 | 150 |
| A | 01/2024 | **0** |
| A | 02/2024 | 250 |
| B | 12/2023 | 500 |
| B | 01/2024 | 600 |
| B | 02/2024 | 500 |

However, since there is no data for product A in January, the whole month is being skipped and the data is like this:

| Product | month | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12/2023 | 150 |
| A | 02/2024 | 250 |
| B | 12/2023 | 500 |
| B | 01/2024 | 600 |
| B | 02/2024 | 500 |

Now I have a problem, since the data entries are not the same for every product and some data for some months is missing.

Is there a way to change the collection proccess/code to have a 0 rather than  askipped month in the output?

Comment: It will likely require some SQL manipulation or handling arrays at PHP side to include that missing data. However, why not handle these scenarios in front-end while displaying, to "pad" missing records with 0s, instead of increasing data size being returned from server?